# <lightning:button> does not work

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Why does `<ui:button>` work but `<lightning:button>` does not work?

**Component:**

```
<aura:component>
    <ltng:require 
        styles="{!$Resource.SLDS212 + '/assets/styles/lightning-design-system-ltng.css'}"
        scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}"
        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
    <ui:button label="myButton" press="{!c.doSomething}"/>
    <lightning:button name="myButton" onclick="{!c.doSome}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    doSomething: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var button = event.getSource().get("v.label");
        alert(button);

    },
    doSome: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var button = event.getSource().get("v.name");
        alert(button);

    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name attribute is optional, use label

```
<lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{! c.doSome }" />
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_button.htm

You may get an error on getSource() if you are on winter box, there seems to be a fix in Spring 17:

[Lockerservice and event.getSource()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/lockerservice-and-event-getsource/155327)

[Winter 17 release : event.getSource is not a function on lightning:button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144129/winter-17-release-event-getsource-is-not-a-function-on-lightningbutton)

Comment: Yeah, that tripped me up, too. Silly Lightning.

Comment: One more thing : You may get an error on getSource() if you are on winter box, there seems to be a fix in Spring 17 http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/lockerservice-and-event-getsource/155327